# book module navigation horizontal submenu

Tags: routes, nodes

I am using the book module navigation block to display links to book pages. I was wondering if it was possible to alter it so rather than the children links appearing below the parent, they would appear to the side. This is because I want a horizontal navigation

Thanks

EDIT:
For anyone wondering, the way to get book links to appear on the same level, you just need to make sure the child pages are pointing to the same parent, then just display that level of links to get a nav bar, styled this gives you a horizontal nav bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override **node.tpl.php** and customize where to render `$content['book_navigation']`.

Have also look at [book-navigation.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book-navigation.tpl.php/7) and [template_preprocess_book_navigation()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/template_preprocess_book_navigation/7).